# Мне нужно получить ссылки и ссылку, как сделать без дубликации кода

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Т.е мне нужно 2 метода по получению ссылки и ссылок. Проблема в том, что просто нельзя сделать 1 метод,из которого вернуть коллекцию и из него взять первый элемент(если нужна 1ссылка). На это уйдет больше времени, чем вернуть 1 ссылку. В голове сейчас только реализации паттерна шаблонный метод, но я не знаю как его туда поставить.

Вот проблемный код

```
 public async Task<string> GetWorkingLink(string htmlContent)
        {
            IDocument angleDocument = await _publicHttp.Context.OpenAsync(html => html.Content(htmlContent));

            foreach (var linksElement in angleDocument.QuerySelector("#b_results")?.QuerySelectorAll("cite"))
            {
                string workingLink = linksElement.TextContent;

                var httpResponse = await _publicHttp.Client.GetAsync(workingLink);

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var siteHtml = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var filmNamesCollection = await new SiteParser().GetPopularFilmsName(siteHtml, 5);

                if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                return workingLink;
            }

            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["BackUpLink"].ConnectionString;
        }
```

Итак, проблема тут

```
 if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                return workingLink;
```

Мне нужно вернуть ссылку, либо добавить в коллекцию эту ссылку, взависимости какой метод выберут. Как мне это сделать без дубликации кода?

Что мне нужно, как я это вижу сейчас

```
 public async Task<string> GetWorkingLink(string htmlContent)
        {
            IDocument angleDocument = await _publicHttp.Context.OpenAsync(html => html.Content(htmlContent));

            foreach (var linksElement in angleDocument.QuerySelector("#b_results")?.QuerySelectorAll("cite"))
            {
                string workingLink = linksElement.TextContent;

                var httpResponse = await _publicHttp.Client.GetAsync(workingLink);

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var siteHtml = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var filmNamesCollection = await new SiteParser().GetPopularFilmsName(siteHtml, 5);

                if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                return workingLink;
            }

            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["BackUpLink"].ConnectionString;
        }

 public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetWorkingLinks(string htmlContent)
        {
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            IDocument angleDocument = await _publicHttp.Context.OpenAsync(html => html.Content(htmlContent));

            foreach (var linksElement in angleDocument.QuerySelector("#b_results")?.QuerySelectorAll("cite"))
            {
                string workingLink = linksElement.TextContent;

                var httpResponse = await _publicHttp.Client.GetAsync(workingLink);

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var siteHtml = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var filmNamesCollection = await new SiteParser().GetPopularFilmsName(siteHtml, 5);

                if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                links.Add(workingLink);
            }

            return links;
        }
```

Разница

```
if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                return workingLink;
            }

            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["BackUpLink"].ConnectionString;
```

```
if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
                links.Add(workingLink);
            }

            return links;
```

Я хочу сделать это без дубляжа кода, не повторяя пол метода, ради 2ух строк

Comment: Создайте воспроизводимый пример, ничего пока непонятно.

Comment: Как я его создам, если я не знаю как сделать то что мне надо

Comment: Обновил вопросс

Comment: У меня просто архитектурный вопрос, тут воспроизводить ничего не надо, все отлично работает. Просто мне нужно сделать без дубликации кода

Comment: Разница у вас в чем? В том, что 1-й метод берет первую попавшуюся ссылку и ее возвращает, а 2-й выводит все? Если да, то сделайте `yield` возвращение, тогда у вас будет некий контроль над тем, что получаете. То есть, самое базовое, будет нечто [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AeGSCU), если надо чисто 1-й или все, без просчитывания всей коллекции, то это один из вариантов решения. Только учтите, для `async` там немного иначе (почитайте про `IAsyncEnumerable` из C#8).

Comment: Спасибо, мне кажется это подходит. А что мне делать, если у меня нету c# 8.0, я использую netframework 4.8, Как мне без IAsyncEnumerable? Все внутри в Task и .Wait()?

Comment: А кто сказал, что у вас нету c#8? Последний .Framework спокойно может использовать большинство нововведений c#8, достаточно указать в `.csproj` версию языка (`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` или прям версию `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>`), а также, для `IAsyncEnumerable` установить через NuGet пакет `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`. Также для сборки может потребоваться пакет `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. Если у вас Visual Studio 2017, то новый код будет подсвечивать ошибками, но проект успешно соберется. Ну а так, **пора обновляться до .NET6!**.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях вас советовали использовать yield - это хороший совет.

Но если всё-таки столкнулись с проблемами при обновлении на новую версию, то можете использовать ещё и вот такой вариант:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetWorkingLinksAsync(string htmlContent, int? linksMaxCount = null)
    {
        // TODO: валидация входных параметров

        List<string> links = new List<string>();
        IDocument angleDocument = await _publicHttp.Context.OpenAsync(html => html.Content(htmlContent));

        foreach (var linksElement in angleDocument.QuerySelector("#b_results")?.QuerySelectorAll("cite"))
        {
            string workingLink = linksElement.TextContent;

            var httpResponse = await _publicHttp.Client.GetAsync(workingLink);

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var siteHtml = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var filmNamesCollection = await new SiteParser().GetPopularFilmsName(siteHtml, 5);

            if (filmNamesCollection.Count() == 5)
            {
                links.Add(workingLink);

                if (linksMaxCount != null && links.Count == linksMaxCount)
                {
                    // если ссылок уже достаточное количество - выходим
                    return links;
                }
            }
        }

        return links;
    }
```

Т.е. просто добавьте необязательный параметр, который определяет сколько ссылок вернуть.

Если надо вернуть все, то просто вызывайте метод без этого параметра.

Если нужна только одна ссылка, то укажите linksMaxCount = 1.

P.s. Так же не забывайте, что названия асинхронных методов должны заканчиваться на Async.